# How can I develop with the full angular.js but deploy to production with angular.min.js?

Tags: angularjs, deployment, minify

When developing webapps with AngularJS and hosting them temporally on my local computer, it's better to use the un-minified `angular.js` because the minified file has much less useful error messages. However, when deploying to production, it's better to use `angular.min.js`.

Is there an automated way to update the `<script src=...>` tag in `index.html` from `...angular.js` to `...angular.min.js` just when deploying?

Comment: @YangLi I don't think source maps solve the problem with AngularJS. The non-minified version includes much more details about an error than the minified version. It's not just accurate line numbers and clearer object names.

Comment: What build tools are using?

Comment: @YangLi I'm just using `grunt`, but I'm willing to incorporate more tools.

Comment: Well with grunt, you can write a grunt, you can create a task for dev that copies the angular non minified version as 'angular.min.js' and for production copy the angular.min.js as the 'angular.min.js'. This way you dont have to worry about changing the name, all it does is change the contents for dev and prod with the name staying the same.

Comment: Using grunt the copy (although I'm not sure if copy allows you to alter the name of your dest) if not you can just use grunt concat but dont concat any files.

Comment: What tools can you incorporate? Are you using java and maven on your backend?

Comment: @YangLi That's a good idea. Right now I'm using a CDN for the angular source so I'd have serve it locally if I wanted to do that, but it would solve the problem.

Comment: @GuillaumeD. I'm using Python and Flask on the backend. I deploy to Heroku with git.

Comment: @drs if ur using a cdn then what u can do is have two index.html files in your src one for dev and other for prod. I'd imagine since ur using angular there wont be much in your index.html so you dont have to worry about updating both.  The other thing which u can do is if u use jade or some sort of template u can also pass variables inside so you can set environment variables